# How to add WS security element to SOAP request on powershell?

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap

I got pretty standard powershell script that sends request to web service:

```
$ws = New-WebServiceProxy -uri "http://server:7801/path/service?wsdl"
$ws | get-member -type method
$ws.service.OverloadDefinitions

$header = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1801_service_wsdl.header
$data = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1801_esb_service_wsdl.data

# $header
# $data

$header.channel = ...
$data.Password = ...     
$bar = $ws.service($header, $data)
```

It works fine, and now I want to add oasis ws-security component to the request's SOAP header:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>Yolo McSwaggen</wsse:Username>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Have you by any chance found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @AlexSarafian Sorry, but no.